# Are the C++ ARM compilers bundled along with VS2008 redistributable?

Tags: c++, windows-ce

Are the VS2008 C++ ARM compilers targeting the WinCE operating system redistributable? Or does Microsoft provide a separate redistributable package (SDK?) ? I am looking for a C++ ARM compiler (actually a complete build environment) for WinCE which I can distribute along with my application for free. What are my options here?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to bundle the compiler, rather than built binaries?

Comment: @Rowland: I need to generate C++ code at run-time.

Comment: @Ctrl Alt D-1337: You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be rather suprised if it were, your use case is rather uncommon. I don't remember seeing them in the redist.txt file, either.

My first instinct would be GCC, as it can target ARM and is also redistributable under GPL.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1DACDB3D-50D1-41B2-A107-FA75AE960856&displaylang=en) is specifically targeted for WinCE and it's a free download.  I'm not sure about redistributing it tho.  Also it's getting old.